# How to store the output of a for loop as a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

- This is the code below I want the output as: ("java developer" OR
  "software developer") AND (angular) AND (core OR j2ee)
  so AND has to be added for every output of for loop  please help me-

```
 x=input("Enter job title:").split()
 y=input("enter primary skills:").split()
 t=input("enter secondary skills").split()
 for i in range(len(x)):
     if len(x)==1:
         print("("+ x[0]+")")
     elif i==0:
         ["("+ x[i] +" OR "]
         print("("+ x[i] +" OR ", end= " ")
     elif i==(len(d)-1):
         print(x[i] +")")
     else:
         print(x[i] + " OR ", end= " ")

 for i in range(len(y)):
     if len(y)==1:
         print("("+ y[0]+")")
     elif i==0:
         print("("+ y[i] +" OR ", end= " ")
     elif i==(len(y)-1):
         print(y[i] +")")
     else:
         print(y[i] + " OR ", end= " ")

 for i in range(len(t)):
     if len(t)==1:
         print("("+ t[0]+")")
     elif i==0:
         print("("+ t[i] +" OR ", end= " ")
     elif i==(len(t)-1):
         print(t[i] +")")
     else:
         print(t[i] + " OR ", end= " ")
```

i am getting output as

Execution:

```
Enter job title: javadeveloper software developer
enter primary skills: angular
enter secondary skills: core j2ee
(javadeveloper OR  software OR  developer)
(angular)
(core OR  j2ee)
```

I want the output as:  ("java developer" OR "software developer") AND (angular) AND (core OR j2ee)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

check the following code:

```
from operator import indexOf


x = input("Enter job title:").replace(" developer","developer").split()
y=input("enter primary skills:").split()
t=input("enter secondary skills").split()
for i in range(len(x)):
    varx = x[i]
    if x[i].endswith("developer"):
        varx = varx.replace("developer", " developer")
        varx = '"' + varx +'"'   

    if len(x)==1:
        print("("+ varx+")", end =" ")
    elif i==0:
        ["("+ varx +" OR "]
        print("("+ varx +" OR ", end= " ")
    elif i==(len(x)-1):
        print(varx +")", end =" ")
    else:
        print(varx + " OR ", end= " ")

print(" AND ", end =" ")

for i in range(len(y)):
    if len(y)==1:
        print("("+ y[0]+")", end =" ")
    elif i==0:
        print("("+ y[i] +" OR ", end= " ")
    elif i==(len(y)-1):
        print(y[i] +")", end =" ")
    else:
        print(y[i] + " OR ", end= " ")

print(" AND ", end =" ")

for i in range(len(t)):
    if len(t)==1:
        print("("+ t[0]+")", end =" ")
    elif i==0:
        print("("+ t[i] +" OR ", end= " ")
    elif i==(len(t)-1):
        print(t[i] +")", end =" ")
    else:
        print(t[i] + " OR ", end= " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is pretty confusing because of all the string manipulation. A better way to do this would be to first build a model of what you want, and then print it out.

The model could be a list of lists. Each item in the inner list should be 'OR'ed, and each item in the outer list should be 'AND'ed. So for your example, we would represent it as:

```
model = [
    ["java developer", "software developer"],
    ["angular"],
    ["core", "j2ee"],
]
```

---

### Step 1: Generate the Model

It seems that terms can have multiple words, so splitting on whitespace is going to be ambiguous here. Instead we could split on something like `,`.

We want to make everything as generic as possible, so here's a function that parses a string of comma separated terms into a list of terms. We can use this every time we want to take input from the user.

```
def parse_input_string(inp: str) -> list[str]:
    return [s.strip() for s in inp.split(",")]

# e.g. parse_input_string("foo, bat bar") => ["foo", "bat bar"]
```

### Step 2: Print the model

We can write a function that takes a row, and outputs an 'OR' statement. And then use that to write a function that gets the entire query statement.

```
def get_or_statement(items: list[str]) -> str:
    # if there's a space in a term, wrap the term in quotes.
    items = (f'"{item}"' if " " in item else item for item in items)
    return f"({' OR '.join(items)})"

def get_query(model: list[list[str]]) -> str:
    or_statements = [get_or_statement(items) for items in model]
    return " AND ".join(or_statements)

print(get_query(model))
# ("java developer" OR "software developer") AND (angular) AND (core OR j2ee)
```

### Step 3: Wrap it all together

Then our final program becomes quite simple:

```
model = [
    parse_input_string(input("Enter job titles (comma separated): ")),
    parse_input_string(input("Enter primary skills (comma separated): ")),
    parse_input_string(input("Enter secondary skills (comma separated): ")),
]
print(get_query(model))
```

*Output*

```
Enter job titles (comma separated): java developer, software developer
Enter primary skills (comma separated): angular
Enter secondary skills (comma separated): core, j2ee
("java developer" OR "software developer") AND (angular) AND (core OR j2ee)
```